# How to store cell's selection, need best practice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

### Situation

There is a table view shows list of articles: Article.
An article is a struct object and is list of articles are initialized form api response.

We needs to add a feature that when a user taps a cell, it changes to selected state. To indicate the selection, I add a check mark to a selected item cell.

```
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
```

### Problem

#### Problem

Here comes a problem.  Since **cells are recycled**, each time a selected article cell is dequed, we **need to store which cell is selected.**

struct Article is used within entire app so we **shouldn’t** just **add isSelected field** to it.

```
struct Article {
    let title: String
    var isSelected: Bool // <- Not good.  Article used over the app.
}
```

#### Temorary solution

Some solution I use is to make bool array to store which row is selected.

```
var selectedRow: Bool = {
    return articles.map { return false }
}()
```

But this approach seems odd and is also vulnerable to cell insettion and deletion.

### Question

Is there a better solution?

### The odd way solution code

```
import UIKit

struct Article {
    let title: String
}

class SampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    
    let articles: [Article] = {
        var tempArticles: [Article] = []
        for i in 0...30 {
            tempArticles.append(Article(title: "Article at index:\(i)"))
        }
        return tempArticles
    }()
    
    lazy var selectedRow: [Bool] = {
        return articles.map { _ in false }
    }()
  
    let cellId = "cell"
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }


    

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return articles.count
    }

    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = articles[indexPath.row].title
        
        // Set selected state to a cell
        cell.accessoryType = selectedRow[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Table view delegate
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update selection
        // This isn't the best way to update selection but just to make the example simple.
        selectedRow[indexPath.row] = !selectedRow[indexPath.row]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try the Multiple Selector Row in [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka)

Comment: Try using tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this: Give the table view it's own model that saves the state of the list including the selected state.

```
class ListItem {
    let article: Article
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

Then build your table view from an array of these items:

```
var listItems = [ListItem]()
```

Populate that array with ListItems holding your articles and use it as the data source.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    let item = listItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.article.title 
    cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

And finally in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you just have to set the new `isSelected` value of the selected list item.

Comment: Your answer was simpler and more flexible so I chose it over "Set<Article>" way.
Btw I also enhanced your answer using generic type.  Check my new answer!

Comment: that's a great idea! 

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `Set<Article>` to track your selected articles.  In order to do this, your `Article` struct needs to be `Hashable`.  As long as all of the properties of your struct are `Hashable` then all you need to do is add conformance to the `Hashable` protocol.

```
struct Article: Hashable {
    let title: String
}


var selectedArticles = Set<Article>()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    let article = articles[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = article.title

    // Set selected state to a cell
    cell.accessoryType = selectedArticles.contains(article) ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}


// MARK: - Tabkle view delegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let article = article[indexPath.row]
    if selectedArticles.contains[article] {
        selectedArticles.remove(article)
    } else {
        selectedArticles.insert(article)
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: I could't come up with "Set"! Also great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I **enhanced** Dorian Roy's answer by **using generic type**.

In this way we **only need to declare it once**, not for every type of models

```
struct SelectableListItem<T> {
    let item: T
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

Table View Implementation

```
    var listItems: [SelectableListItem<Article>] = []

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        let listItem = listItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = listItem.item.title
        cell.accessoryType = listItem.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update data
        listItems[indexPath.row].isSelected = !listItems[indexPath.row].isSelected

        // Update selection
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = listItems[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
```

Comment: You have to be careful with using a struct and modifying the property since strict are value types and are copied on modify.

Comment: You could also avoid the generic and define a protocol `Selectable` that had a Boolean var `selected`. This is probably a better approach semantically since that would allow you to define a thing that was selectable whereas the generic gives you something that is selectable that has a thing associated with it